# PostgreSQL Hibernate and Intellij IDEA results in org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"'

Tags: java, hibernate

I use PostgreSQL, Intellij IDEA, Spring MVC, Hibernate.

When I'm trying retrieve list of users from table "Users" I recieve exception like below:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [idea] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [select * from "Users"]] with root cause
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [select * from "Users"].

When I trying execute  SQL query (`select * from "Users"`) in DB console it working fine.

Here's me code when I recieve exception:

```
public List listUser() {
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
      .createQuery("select * from \"Users\"").list();
}
```

Can somebody advice me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `"` and the `select *` from the query, they're not needed:

```
.createQuery("from Users")
```

But is your entity really called `Users` or is this just the table name? Because Hibernate expects you to use the *entity name* in the query.

If you want to query the `Users` table directly, use

```
.createSQLQuery("select * from Users").list();
```

instead, but it'll just return a `List<Object[]>`, with your columns being the elements of the array(s). You can make hibernate do the translation into an entity (I assume it's called `User`) like so:

```
.createSQLQuery("select * from Users").addEntity(User.class).list();
```

Though I really recommend using the [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql) version for that.

Comment: I changed my entity name to Users and use HQL version. And it works. But I had had to change the table name from Users to users. Even thought I used Users with capital U in query. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :

```
...    
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT * FROM Users").list();
}
```

You can do that too with HQL Query :

```
         ...
         String HQL = "FROM Users";
         return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(HQL);
    }
```

Comment: Now I have exception like this: 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [idea] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM Users]] with root cause
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM Users]

Comment: Try with HQL Query , ("from Users") or your entity name.
 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 0):

So as you are using HQL, your query should be:

```
select from Users
```

assuming your `Entity` class is `Users`

Or just `from Users`